# Outlier rules in JFreeChart Boxplots?

Tags: jfreechart, rule, boxplot, outliers, iqr

i've got some questions regarding outlier rules in JFreeChart:

1. Is it possible to influence the outlier rules in a JFreeChart Boxplot?
2. I would assume that the default setting for outliers is Q3+1.5*IQR and Q1-1.5*IQR?
3. Is there a default rule for extreme values like Q3+3*IQR and Q1-3*IQR?
4. Maybe this should be a separate Question but how do you set the symbol for outliers? The default setting is a circle which is too big for my preference.

My data is in a DefaultBoxAndWhiskerCategoryDataset and i am not even sure if i need to change any of the default settings. Nevertheless it would be nice to know what exactly the default settings are ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use the source, Luke. [`DefaultBoxAndWhiskerCategoryDataset`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/statistics/DefaultBoxAndWhiskerCategoryDataset.html) calculates the outlier values, and the corresponding  [`BoxAndWhiskerRenderer`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/category/BoxAndWhiskerRenderer.html) draws them. Click on either class name link to see the [source](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/data/statistics/DefaultBoxAndWhiskerCategoryDataset.html#line.73) [code](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/renderer/category/BoxAndWhiskerRenderer.html#line.128).

Comment: What is he supposed to do with it? Does he have to create his own Renderer to do it? Are there no methods provided to change the outliers' symbol?

Comment: @CGFoX: I don't see any methods to change the outliers' shape; the `BoxAndWhiskerCategoryDataset` controls the calculation; return an empty `List` to hide them.

Comment: Are the whiskers calculated as Q1-1.5*IQR and Q3+1.5*IQR? That's what it seems to me in the code, but I want to make sure.

Answer (score 2):

The actual place where these values are calculated is in the [BoxAndWhiskerCalculator](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/data/statistics/BoxAndWhiskerCalculator.html)
class, in the [BoxAndWhiskerCalculator](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/data/statistics/BoxAndWhiskerCalculator.html#line.94) function.

In essence outliers are the values outside the "regular range", defined as the maximum range defined by values between Q1-2*IQR and Q1-1.5*IQR on the lower side, and between Q3+1.5*IQR and Q3+2*IQR on the upper side.

The far-out range for extreme values is below Q1-2*IQR or above Q3+2*IQR.

By changing these criteria in the above-mentioned function you can change the behaviour of the plot.

The symbols are drawn in the [BoxAndWhiskerRenderer](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/renderer/category/BoxAndWhiskerRenderer.html) class, in particular in the [drawEllipse](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/renderer/category/BoxAndWhiskerRenderer.html#line.987), [drawMultipleEllipse](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/renderer/category/BoxAndWhiskerRenderer.html#line.1001), [drawHighFarOut](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/renderer/category/BoxAndWhiskerRenderer.html#line.1020) and [drawLowFarOut](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/renderer/category/BoxAndWhiskerRenderer.html#line.1036) methods.

Comment: So how do you actually change the symbol?